# Xpages clarification of memory allocation

Tags: xpages

When creating new notes object in java, object is created on heap in c++ and JVM stores only reference.
Since JVM has no knowledge of created objects on heap, we must manually clear them using .recycle(). So far so good.

The question is, are objects automatically recycled after each request. My guess is this holds true for request scope. Im not sure about session and viewScope...

I searched for a solution to count notes objects on heap. Best I got was "sh memory dump" and comparing delta of "free total". Results were confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Notes object get automatically recycled after each HTTP request.

You can't put Notes objects into viewScope, sessionScope or applicationScope as Notes classes are not serializable.

Have a look at [Tim Tripcony's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19800858/2065611) for more details.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Just for the sake of complete answer, do you know for a tool to inspect number of domino objects allocated?

Comment: No, unfortunately I don't. We wrote a utility class to monitor Notes objects a while ago. We put document, view and database objects with a key into a List and checked before recycling if those used elsewhere (which would be bad if such an object would be recycled).

Comment: Heap Dump is such tool.